# Making personal terminal and dont know how to make a simple "search {username}" CMD for sherlock without needing to exit out of the python script CD

Tags: python, terminal, project

This is the structurte of the code im using:

```
while True:
    command = input (">- ")
    if command == "exit":
        break
    elif command == "clear":
        os.system("cls")
    elif ...and so on....
```

(this isnt the whole code but should be enough to understand how im writing this)

anyone know how i can add a cmd here that uses sherlock without needing to exit out of the terminal and back into a windows terminal?

tried using a "import sherlock" but dont know how to add it to this particular project

Comment: Which [`sherlock`](https://pypi.org/search/?q=sherlock) are you talking about, how is a Python module related to a terminal ? _tried using a "import sherlock"_ is there any error ?

Comment: yea there came back an error saying that "search" wasnt a valid or known command